# Is there any clean way to add custom TypeAdapters to AngularBeans Json-Serializer?

Tags: java, json, angular, jakarta-ee, serialization

Because of some serialization problems I'd like to add custom TypeAdapters to AngularBeans Gson-Builder.

- https://github.com/bessemHmidi/AngularBeans

In the class `AngularBeansUtils` I already found the `initJsonSerialiser()` method where the serializer ist built but I could not find any solution to add my adapters without overwriting the class. (Attributes private and no methods to access them)

Has anyone experienced the same problem or can help me out with a clean approach to add my adapters?